# Laravel 9 Migration ForeginKey not created

Tags: laravel, mariadb, innodb, database-migration, artisan-migrate

I have some problem with the Laravel 9 migrations. After i run the "php artisan migrate" command every table created with the indexes. So everthings just fine except the foregin key. I don't have any idea why, maybe someone know what causes the problem or have a solotion. Thank you all!

10.4.22-MariaDB 
InnoDB 
Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1m PHP/8.1.2 
phpMyAdmin: 5.11.1

My migrations:

```
Schema::create('supplier_orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('Id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('Warehouse', false)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('Supplier', false)->nullable(false);
    $table->dateTime('StartedAt')->nullable(false)->useCurrent();
    $table->dateTime('CompletedAt')->default(null);
    $table->string('PrimeVoucherNumber', 100)->nullable(false);
    $table->index(['CompletedAt', 'Warehouse', 'Supplier'], 'CompletedWarehouseSupplier');
});

Schema::create('supplier_order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('Id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('SupplierOrder', false)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('Employee', false)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('Product', false)->nullable(false);
    $table->unsignedDecimal('Quantity', 18, 4)->nullable(false);
    $table->index(['SupplierOrder', 'Employee', 'Product'], 'OrderEmployeeProduct')->unique();
    $table->index(['Product', 'SupplierOrder', 'Quantity'], 'ProductOrder');
    });

Schema::table('supplier_order_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('SupplierOrder', 'FK_SupplierOrderDetail_SupplierOrder')->references('Id')->on('supplier_orders')->onDelete('CASCADE')->onUpdate('NO ACTION');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, there is no error in the migartions, just me. 
I am just a big donkey. 
I found it in the phpmyadmin under "Table->Structure->Realation view" 
I thought that i will found it under "Table->Structure->Table structure->Indexes"
Its make no sense to me why is it there, but finally i found it.
Thanks everyone.